# How can I draw a swigly line in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I need to draw a swigly line between two points in Unity using a script, I've just started working with unity 2 weeks ago so I'm new at it.
For reference, this is what I mean by a swigly line

[image: LineRenderer]

Comment: Look up splines

Comment: Please don't use excessive formatting as per your original post. There was no need for any words there to be bold, and it just made it harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a line renderer to draw it, and you should use a function kind of

```
for(x=0; x<length; x++)

Y = sin(x);

Line.setpoint(x,y,0);
```